# tensorflow keras evaluate function runs for too long

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried to use model.evaluate in Google Colab with the following code:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                              batch_size = 20,
                                              class_mode = 'binary', 
                                              target_size = (image_size, image_size))
results = model.evaluate(test_generator)
for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, results):
  print(name, ': ', value)
```

I get the following output in the console:
Found 624 images belonging to 2 classes.
I was expecting the model.evaluate to complete in ceil(624 / 20) = 32 steps.
Instead the function seems to be running forever (well over 1000 steps).
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up specifying the steps parameter

```
results = model.evaluate(test_generator, steps=len(test_generator))
```

len(test_generator) is equal to 32 as expected